# two submit buttons in one form executing two different servlets

Tags: html, servlets

i have a form having two submit buttons.
one for creating a user and other for logging in an existing user.
how can i fire two different servlets from these two buttons keeping them in one single form??

like if create button is clicked then create.java is executed
and if login button is fired then login.java is executed

Comment: it depends, you can always only use 1 `submit` button per html `form`. Solutions: if you use `GET` as method, you can make one `submit` a normal `button` and link to the other page (in your case not recommended), you can do it with `JavaScript`, or you can wrap them with two different forms...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with JavaScript, this is an example using jQuery ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#id_of_your_button').click(function() {

            // do some stuff here, e.g.
            var str = $("#your_html_form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "url_to_your_file",
          data: str,
          success: function(msg) {

                      //...

              }
        }); 
        }

        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
});
```

EDIT:

if you want to do it without JavaScript, you can do it like `<a href="page-to-register-new-user"><input type="button" value="register"></a>`

Otherwise, if you want the form submitted right away, you could only take two forms, or use JavaScript (also in other ways, as you could e.g. change the action-url with JavaScript depending on which button the user clicks, etc)...

... but there is only one "Submit" button allowed per HTML-form.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial about the onclick event for HTML buttons: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyText()
{
document.getElementById("field2").value=document.getElementById("field1").value;
}
</script>

<button onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</button>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)

Comment: actually i dont prefer javascript.
is there any other way this can be solved??

Comment: @user1506349: are you linking to another page only?

Comment: @user1506349 What would you want besides JavaScript?